# Can a NFC tag be read over a large flat area

Tags: nfc

Was wondering if I could create a large flat area that could detect the position of NFC tag (or similar preferably powerless technology) and if possible the direction the chip is facing. Say if you had a chessboard and placed a pawn that had a nfc tag on it, could a computer recognize this as a pawn and where it's going and facing. There wouldn't be much vertical distance but a lot of horizontal area.

It would also be great if you could point to subreddits or other resources with similar technologies if this is not feasable.

Comment: Put a coil under each square, and multiplex them into one reader.

Comment: You could actually have four coils per square, and two per chess piece.

Comment: But really: does it *have* to be NFC? sounds much like a cheap camera, plus maybe a lens and mirrors in cheap plastic with specially marked piece bottom pieces would be way, way easier and not actually much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky - NFC is not designed to do this, and it's not really designed to cope with lots of readers in a small area either. If you did go for one per square, you'd have to program them to make sure that only one was active at any one time, and then cycle rapidly through all of them. The final result might be quite slow.

"Traditional" chess computers avoid all of this by not actually identifying the pieces individually. They know the starting layout, and they can tell which squares have a piece on them (contact or IR-reflective proximity sensors). They then watch for a "piece removed then piece placed" sequence and assume it's the same piece.

There are various tools like the Apple Pencil which provide very precise identification of where they are on a capacitative touchscreen. But they work by emitting a signal themselves, so require charging, and active electronics in 64 chess pieces is likely to be a huge pain.

You could perhaps borrow something from the [Tritiled](https://hackaday.io/project/11864-tritiled) project and put an extremely low power microprocessor, battery and LED in each piece, and then have it emit an extremely short, dim, pulse-coded flash downwards into the board where sensors could read it. Best case battery life would be a few years from a coin cell.

Or - as has just occured to me - put a coil in the board and each piece, and use *that* to power all the individual identification lights.

Comment: If I wanted to go the IR reflective/led way, would I have to make the board clear? Because it seems like an IR signal wouldn't go through an opaque surface very well

Comment: You can get materials that look black or white opaque to humans but are transparent to IR